# Why is the value of a suite variable lost after importing it from a resource file?

Tags: robotframework

From what I read about variable scopes and importing resource files in [robotframework doc](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id487) i would expect this to work (python 2.7, RF 2.8.7):

Test file:

```
*** Settings *** 
Resource          VarRes.txt 
Suite Setup       Preconditions

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
VarDemo
    Log To Console    imported [${TODAY}]

*** Keywords ***
```

Resource file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DateTime

*** Variables ***
${TODAY}          ${EMPTY}    # Initialised during setup, see keyword Preconditions

*** Keywords ***
Format Local Date
    [Arguments]    ${inc}    ${format}    
    ${date} =    Get Current Date    time_zone=local    increment=${inc} day    result_format=${format}
    [Return]    ${date}    # formatted date

Preconditions
    ${TODAY} =   Format Local Date    0    %Y-%m-%d
    Log To Console    inited [${TODAY}]
```

However the output is:

```
inited [2015-03-20]
imported []
```

RF documentation states:

> Variables with the test suite scope are available anywhere in the test
>   suite where they are defined **or imported**. They can be created in
>   Variable tables, **imported from resource** and ....

which I think is done here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add a line to keyword Preconditions like this, it works:

```
Preconditions
    ${TODAY} =   Format Local Date    0    %Y-%m-%d
    Set Suite Variable  ${TODAY}
    Log To Console    inited [${TODAY}]
```

The reason is that in the first line a local variable is defined, instead of initialising the test suite variable declared in the variable table. A paragraph in RF doc hints to that:

> Variables set during the test execution either using return values
>   from keywords or using Set Test/Suite/Global Variable keywords always
>   override possible existing variables in the scope where they are set

I think a major drawback of RF is that you cannot define variables dynamically in the variable table. Setting the scope of a variable from within a keyword is something I try to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic variables, you might to use a variable file in Python. See the section ["Implementing variable file as Python or Java class" in the User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#implementing-variable-file-as-python-or-java-class).

For example, I use a variables.py with:

```
if platform.system() in ['Darwin', 'Linux']:
    OS_FAMILY = 'unix'
elif platform.system() == 'Windows':
    OS_FAMILY = 'windows'
else:
    OS_FAMILY = 'unknown'
OS_FAMILY_IS_UNIX = OS_FAMILY == 'unix'      
OS_FAMILY_IS_WINDOWS = OS_FAMILY == 'windows'
```

Then in the Robot Tests I can use the dynamic variables ${OS_FAMILY}, ${OS_FAMILY_IS_UNIX}, and ${OS_FAMILY_IS_WINDOWS} anywhere.

You should be able to do create your ${TODAY} variable.